# Center Bootstrap Row and Spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center, footer, html

I'm trying to center a Row and the spans inside of it with bootsrap.

You can see it in the footer here:
http://www.divisionforty.com/wall/

I'd like the social networking icons to be on the left, copyright in the middle the powered by on the right, as it all is.

footer code:

```
<div id="footer">

        <div id="footer-content">


                <div id="footer-bottom" class="clear">



                      <div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="span12" style="width:100%;">
<div class="span2" style="text-align:left;">
<a href="https://twitter.com/WallSpaceOttawa"><img alt="twitter" class="social" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/twitter.png"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Wall-Space-Gallery-and-Framing/195974620432391"> 
<img alt="facebook" class="social" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/facebook.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="span6" style="text-align:center;">

<h5>
  Copyright &#169; <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
                                    var dteNow = new Date();
                                    var intYear = dteNow.getFullYear();
                                    document.write(intYear);
          //]]>
          </script>
          Wall Space Gallery And Framing - All Rights Reserved.

</h5>
</div>

<div class="span4" style="text-align:right;">
<h5>Powered by <a href="http://divisionforty.com">Division Forty</a></h5>
</div>
</div>

</div>


                </div><!--END FOOTER-BOTTOM-->    

        </div><!--END FOOTER-CONTENT-->        

    </div><!--END FOOTER-->
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Denver

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="footer">

        <div id="footer-content">


                <div id="footer-bottom" class="clear">



                      <div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="span12" style="width:100%;">
<div class="span2 text-left">
<a href="https://twitter.com/WallSpaceOttawa"><img alt="twitter" class="social" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/twitter.png"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Wall-Space-Gallery-and-Framing/195974620432391"> 
<img alt="facebook" class="social" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/facebook.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="span6 text-center">

<h5>
  Copyright &#169; <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
                                    var dteNow = new Date();
                                    var intYear = dteNow.getFullYear();
                                    document.write(intYear);
          //]]>
          </script>
          Wall Space Gallery And Framing - All Rights Reserved.

</h5>
</div>

<div class="span4 text-right">
<h5>Powered by <a href="http://divisionforty.com">Division Forty</a></h5>
</div>
</div>

</div>


                </div><!--END FOOTER-BOTTOM-->    

        </div><!--END FOOTER-CONTENT-->        

    </div><!--END FOOTER-->
```

You can use the built in alignment classes `text-left`, `text-right`, and `text-center`

Comment: for some reason when I add that the span12 extends off the page, because of the width:100%, however when I remove that width:100% the powered by gets removed

Comment: Try removing the span12 wrapper that's around the elements

Comment: Is there a alternative to spans because it doesn't seem to be working to great

Comment: Not very familiar with bootstrap 2 so I'm not sure.

Comment: doesn't have to be with bootstrap, just in general

Answer (score 0):

Is it your design to let footer full width as screen width?

if yes, you just have to change your row class to row-fluid class.
Bootstrap 2.3.2 is using row-fluid, not row.

```
<div id="footer">
     <div id="footer-content">
          <div id="footer-bottom" class="clear">
                  <div class="row-fluid" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="span12" style="width:100%;">

        <div class="span2 text-left">
        </div>

        <div class="span6 text-center">
        </div>

        <div class="span4 text-right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            </div><!--END FOOTER-BOTTOM-->    
    </div><!--END FOOTER-CONTENT-->        
</div><!--END FOOTER-->
```

if no, put a container for the width.

Comment: Is there a alternative to spans because it doesn't seem to be working to great, the intention is for it to be full width