# Centring a span in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-frameworks

I'm newbie in Twitter bootstrap. how can I center a `span` in a `parent row`?

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap Version 2.3 and not 3.1 . Since in 3.1 there is a center-block that I cannot not use in 2.3. I have to use 2.3 so don't suggest me to upgrade.

Thanks alo

Comment: Check out this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040301/center-bootstrap-row-and-spans

Maybe this one is actually better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382970/how-to-center-a-box-thing-with-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Add class text-center to the span.

```
<div class="span12 text-center">some text</span>
```

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/110734)**

[Alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html) were released in bootstrap 2.3

Alternatively if you wanted to use your own css classes you could do this in a number of ways, one of them being like so:

### Sample markup

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12 text-center">some text</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.row
{
   text-align: center;
}
.span12
{ 
  display: inline-block;
}
```